# Linked List finding length - whats the difference between these two functions?

Tags: c, linked-list

Is there any difference between these two functions? I mean in-terms of the result returned?

```
int Length(struct node* head) {
  struct node* current = head;
  int count = 0;

  while (current != NULL) {
    count++;
    current = current->next;
  }

  return count;
}
```

and this function

```
int Length(struct node* head) {
  int count = 0;

  while (head != NULL) {
    count++;
    head = head->next;
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: `++count` would be better - it is useful to get into the habit especia;lly when iterators are involved. Also some indentation in the function body/while loop makes it more readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same. One uses a local 'current' variable to iterate over the list, while the other one uses the same variable that was received through the function arguments.

Comment: Hehe, they're both "local" in microscopically different senses: The `current` variable lives in the function *body* scope, while `head` lives in the *function* scope itself, but the space between those two scopes is too thin to stick a knife in.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value will be the same.

The former is the kind of code that would be written by a programmer subscribing to the style rule that says "it is bad practice to modify parameters because they are passed by value and would give the reader a false sense that the function would modify the corresponding argument."

Not necessarily bad advice. It makes the code a little longer, though, but it reads better.  Many readers look at the second and have an initial reaction of "wait, what? changing the head?  Oh... okay, no it's safe...."

Answer (score 0):

No difference. The second version simply uses the function argument itself as a variable to work with in the body, and that's perfectly legitimate. In fact, it's even slightly more efficient than the first version which make a gratuitous copy.

You couldn't use the second version if the argument were declared const, i.e. `int Length(struct node* const head)` -- but since it isn't, you're free to use the argument variable for your own purposes.

Comment: I have a hard time believing a compiler wouldn't optimize that out.

Comment: Depending on your compiler and your settings... sure. In a recent interview, Herb Sutter described a client who "for perfectly legitimate reasons" had to compile and ship everything with zero optimization and all debug symbols, and who a vendor has to take such scenarios into account as well.

Comment: The compiler would probably optimize the assignment out anyway and use the same memory (or CPU register) for the `current` variable. I wouldn't be surprised if both functions ended up being identical at the machine code level.